# Binding a collection to a combobox in XAML with extra conditions

Tags: vb.net, binding, silverlight-4.0

I'm trying a binding to a property in codebehind. This sounds easy, but there are some factors that make it alot more difficult. This is the setup (partial, left out the unneccesary parts):

```
<StackPanel VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="10,10,10,0">
    <data:DataGrid x:Name="dgFilterGrid" HorizontalGridLinesBrush="Transparent" RowBackground="White" VerticalGridLinesBrush="Transparent" MinHeight="200" AutoGenerateColumns="False" >
        <data:DataGrid.Columns>
            <data:DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Property">
                <data:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <ComboBox HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" ItemsSource="{Binding Test}" DisplayMemberPath="Description" />
                    </DataTemplate>
                </data:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
            </data:DataGridTemplateColumn>
        </data:DataGrid.Columns>
    </data:DataGrid>
</StackPanel>
```

And the code behind:

```
Public Sub New()
    InitializeComponent()

    DataContext = Me
    dgFilterGrid.ItemsSource = _FilterCollection
End Sub

Public Property Test As ObservableCollection(Of PropertyData)
```

If I want to use the "Test" property in my Xaml, I cannot access it because the combobox which wants to use the property in inside the datagrid to which I bind the "_FilterCollection". Further, this piece is no MVVM part (it's a Framework part) so I can normally set the collection in the property to the itemssource of the combobox, but the combobox is in a template so I cannot address that control in code.

Does anyone see where I went wrong?